# Flutter: Binding has not yet been initialized

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

After upgrading FLutter to **3.0.0** I got this error when using **compute isolate**,
knowing that I have initialized in main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Comment: try flutter clean. flutter pub update then try to run it

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution for this error in Flutter version >= 3.0:

1. Add this line to your main():

   ```
   void main() async {
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
     DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized(); //<----FIX THE PROBLEM
     //..
   }
   ```

Comment: DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized() NOT fixes the problem.

Answer (score -2):

try this `await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`

Comment: no effect =>  it's not a future

Comment: for me is not working

Comment: That function is not a future