# flutter run firebase storage and firestore in new process or isolate causes binding issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Im building an app where user upload a logo, I have activated resizer extension in firebase storage. hence, all images got uploaded, will be replaced with resized image with same reference but ends with "_600x600.png" instead of ".png".

Taking into account that in the upload function, if I wait for the original file to be uploaded, it does not **guarantee** that the new "600x600.png" done uploading.

My end goal is to get the download URL of the new file. My best method was to run from the client side an isolate function which try to get the new file path, if did not succeed (since it may take a while to upload the resized file) it will wait for 1 second, and re-try and so on...

Hence, if I make it in "new" process, I should not see any harm.

Here is what I did:

1. the global function for uploading:

```
Future updateResizedProfileUrl2(Map<String, dynamic> args) async {
  /// Updating profile cover and logo images urls as individual process
  /// imageType: logo, cover
  String imageType = args['type'];
  print('got into update function');
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseFirestore _fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseStorage _fst = FirebaseStorage.instance;
  while (true) {
    Reference fileRef =
        _fst.ref(profileStorageDir).child('${imageType}_600x600.png');
    try {
      print('checking fileref $fileRef');
      final refStr = await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
      print('got url $refStr');
      _fs.collection(settingsCollection).doc('profile').update(
        {'media.$imageType': refStr},
      );
      print('updating media strrefStr');
      return;
    } catch (e) {
      print('waaiting....');
      print(e);
      sleep(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    }
  }
}
```

2. here my main uploader function

```
MyClass... {
  Future<void> uploadLogoImage(File image) async {
    Reference ref = _fst.ref(profileStorageDir).child('logo.png');
    await ref.putFile(image);
    Map<String, dynamic> args = {
      'type': 'logo',
    };
    print('sent update logo');
    compute(updateResizedProfileUrl2, args);
  }
}
```

but this does not work, with following error:

```
ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Binding has not yet been initialized.
E/flutter (23103): The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
E/flutter (23103): Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
E/flutter (23103): In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
E/flutter (23103): If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter.
E/flutter (23103): #0      BindingBase.checkInstance.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:284:9)
E/flutter (23103): #1      BindingBase.checkInstance (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:366:6)
E/flutter (23103): #2      ServicesBinding.instance (package:flutter/src/services/binding.dart:54:54)
E/flutter (23103): #3      BasicMessageChannel.binaryMessenger (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:166:45)
E/flutter (23103): #4      BasicMessageChannel.send (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:180:38)
E/flutter (23103): #5      FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:201:23)
E/flutter (23103): #6      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:29:54)
E/flutter (23103): #7      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:73:13)
E/flutter (23103): #8      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:47)
E/flutter (23103): #9      updateResizedProfileUrl2 (package:appointments/providers/settings_mgr.dart:33:18)
E/flutter (23103): #10     _IsolateConfiguration.applyAndTime.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:108:21)
E/flutter (23103): #11     Timeline.timeSync (dart:developer/timeline.dart:160:22)
E/flutter (23103): #12     _IsolateConfiguration.applyAndTime (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:106:21)
E/flutter (23103): #13     _spawn (package:flutter/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart:127:67)
E/flutter (23103): #14     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:17)
E/flutter (23103): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
E/flutter (23103):
```

I have initialized firebase since I need it and I understand that isolate has different memory that the main...

Writing: "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" in the global function does not work as well...

How can I achieve the above? or how I fix it ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have a look at the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72991163/unhandled-exception-binding-has-not-yet-been-initialized) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72384617/flutter-binding-has-not-yet-been-initialized) and this [github](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_workmanager/issues/431)

Comment: Thanks, but none has helped

Answer (score 2):

to keep it short, you can not run native code from isolate while firebase storage plugin depends on native code.

what you need is to spawn an isolate with https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler or https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate . Those support plugins, tho not all pluging may work. I can confirm that firebase storage works with isolate_handler.

keep in mind that even with this workaround native code will still run on a main thread, thats the limitation of dart

flutter uses platform channels to communicate with native code, and WidgetsBinding.ensureInitialized() is what it needs to use those channels, thats why you are getting this error.

there was also a problem https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9790 which prevented to firebase storage from working correctly in isolates, but it got fixed recently

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in response, your answer is very informative, I have decided to drop this approach long time ago, I have did the image resizing inside the application and dropped it from firebase storage.